# How to set the DataContext for a View created in DataTemplate from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, datacontext

There are questions on this already, but they don't answer my question.
For example:

```
 <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Databinding:RedScreenViewModel}" >
                <Databinding:RedScreen DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type  Databinding:BlueScreenViewModel}">
                <Databinding:BlueScreen DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
 </ContentControl.Resources>
```

As you can see I am attempting to set the DataContext for the created View hoping that it would use the ViewModel that was used to create it. But when I step through the code behind.. the DataContext is always null. How can I achieve what I want?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you define a `DataTemplate` for your ViewModel class with a View control in it, it will automatically have the `DataContext` set to the ViewModel.

This should work:

```
<ContentControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Databinding:RedScreenViewModel}">
        <Databinding:RedScreen />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Databinding:BlueScreenViewModel}">
        <Databinding:BlueScreen />
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Try setting the DataTemplates in Window.Resources.

Comment: DataContext in the constructor is still null.

Comment: In View constructor? I think DataContext will be set later.

Comment: Oh damn.. let me see if I can subscribe to the DataContextChangedEvent

Comment: You were right. It was set later. Ugh. Subscribing to DataContextChangedEvent seemed to do the trick

Comment: DataContextChangedEvent solves this problem! Many thanks!